# GET method with API's

Tags: api, get-method

I am not familiar with API's so I was hoping someone could help me with a question I have. My company uses Greenhouse as their hiring software for people to apply and we are redoing our career site to be more custom. They want a page where we can display each department with a text icon that has the number of positions open in that department that updates itself and when you go into that page it wants to display the positions for that department a long with the location they are in.

In the Greenhouse.io API section they say

> "This is useful for reporting purposes, or for customers who have
>   built their own tools that they want to use with Greenhouse.  GET
>   methods include Offices, Departments, Candidates, Activity Feed,
>   Applications, Scorecards, Scheduled Interviews, Offers, Jobs, Stages,
>   Job Post, Rejection Reasons, Email Templates, Users, and Sources."

Does this GET method mean I can pull those pieces from the API and display them where ever we need to in the site and it will update automatically? I'm primarily a web designer so this info is a bit new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GET refers in fact to the HTTP methods. Generally, you call the api with GET to retrieve data.
If you want to insert a new data with api, you will use POST for instance.

You can see those http methods here:
http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html